# if statement inside styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

```
export enum SizeEnum {
    Small,
    Large
}

export interface ICheckbox {
    Size: SizeEnum;
}

const Box = styled.div`
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
`
```

In the above code I want to be able to conditionally change the height and width value of `<Box>` based on the prop. How do I do this?

Answer (score 24):

Another way to do this, if you want to add several css styles.

```
import css from "styled-jsx/css";


const Box = styled.div`
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    ${props => props.Size === 'Small' && css`
         height:20px;
         width:20px;
    `}
`
```

Comment: These are all good answers, I wanted to give you a vote since there's no best way to do this as far as the three examples I see here

Answer (score 15):

See [`Logical Operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [`Adapting based on props`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) for more info.

```
// Box.
const Box = styled.div`

  height: ${({Size}) => 
    Size === 'Small' && '25px' ||
    Size === 'Large' && '100px' || 
    '50px'
  };

  width: ${({Size}) => 
    Size === 'Small' && '25px' || 
    Size === 'Large' && '100px' || 
    '50px'
  };

`

// Render.
<Box/> // 50px - Normal.
<Box Size="Small"/> // 25px - Small.
<Box Size="Large"/> // 100px - Large.
```

Comment: when i do that i get a typescript error `[ts] Property 'Size' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, any>'.`

Comment: That's a `TypeScript` issue. [This link might help](https://spectrum.chat/thread/e171886e-02fc-414b-8360-b25e128a4e61).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ternary operator

```
const Box = styled.div`
height: ${props => props.Size === 'Small' ? '20px' : '40px'}
width: ${props => props.Size === 'Small' ? '20px' : '40px'}
`
```

Reference: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics

Comment: Throws error in TypeScript `[ts] Property 'Size' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, any>'`

Comment: I don't know much about typescript but you can try by changing attribute name size --> deviceSize/ device-size

Comment: ZeroDarkThirty, to solve this you should create an prop interface.

interface Props {
    Size: string
}

and you should use on element

const Box = styled.div<Props>`
    height: ${props => props.Size === 'Small' ? '20px' : '40px'}
    width: ${props => props.Size === 'Small' ? '20px' : '40px'}
`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *elvis operator* in something like this:

```
${(props) => props.someValue ? css` width: 20px;` : css` width: 100px; `}
```

Hope this helps someone looking into how to use *logical operators* in *React styled components*.

Answer (score 2):

We can add the if-checks just like `jsx`

```js
const Box = styled.div`
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    ${props => props.Size === 'Small' && `
         height:20px;
         width:20px;
    `}
`
```

Note: No need to include the word `css`

Comment: You want the css`` for syntax highlight :|

Comment: In the official docs, they are not mentioning the css``.
https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Answer (score 1):

You can add interface in TypeScript and use booleans for default, small and large boxes. This example is for those who has more than two choices. In case of two choices, I would use arrow function and `? :` operators.

```
interface Sizes { 
  small?: boolean, 
  large?: boolean 
}

// Box.
const Box = styled.div<Sizes>`
  // p in this case means parameter which can have small and large booleans
  height: ${p => 
    (p.small && '25px') ||
    (large && '100px') || 
    '50px'
  };

  width: ${({Size}) => 
    (small && '25px') || 
    (large && '100px') || 
    '50px'
  };

`

// Render.
<Box/> // 50px - Normal.
<Box small/> // 25px - Small.
<Box large/> // 100px - Large.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actual **if/else** syntax may be used as well, what matters is, the returned value should be a string:

```
const DrawerItemTitle = styled.div<{isExpanded: boolean}>(props => {
    const baseStyles = `
        white-space: nowrap;
    `;
    const expandedStyles = baseStyles + `
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 0.4s;
        text-align: center;
        flex-grow: 1;`
    const notExpandedStyles = baseStyles + `
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0s;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    `;

    if(props.isExpanded) {
        return expandedStyles; 
    }
    else { 
        return notExpandedStyles;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Get rid of all IFs

I know that this question is pretty old but I would like to contribute with one suggestion

Lately I've come up with a pattern to compute the value using an object, I think this ended up being pretty interesting!

```
// types.ts
export type CheckboxSize: 'Small' | 'Large'

export interface ICheckbox {
    Size: CheckboxSize;
}


// styles.ts
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import type { CheckboxSize } from './types.ts' 

interface GetBoxSizeProps { 
  size: CheckboxSize
}

function getBoxSize ({ size }: GetBoxSizeProps) => ({
  'Small': css`
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
  `,
  'Large': css`
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;    
  `,
}[size])

interface BoxProps {
  size: CheckboxSize
}

/*
  Just by placing the function here, it will be automatically 
  called by styled components and computed
*/
const Box = styled.div<BoxProps>`
  ${getBoxSize}

  //other styles...
`

// usage

<Box size="Small" />
<Box size="Large" />
```

My problem with the old "if" and "switch" styles was that after some props, the styles logic often times grow up into something that's quite verbose and hard to mantain

I'm not clamming this pattern as my invention, but I wasn't able to find something similar anywhere!

Hope this help someone :)

Ps: if you use themes, is possible to pass the property to the function and keep it pure!